# SQL Injection Filter IIS

Tags: iis, isapi, sql

Currently running an IIS server with some legacy asp & sql.

I was wondering if there are any good isapi filters which would automate checking for SQL injection attacks ?

Answer (score 4):

URL Scan: http://www.iis.net/extensions/UrlScan  It's build specifically for your situation, as well as other common attacks, and works with most any version of IIS.